# edge label spacing

Tags: spacing, labels, graphs, tikz-graphs, edge

I'm having difficulties with edge labels in a graph. The edges labels are overlapping in the nodes. I'd just like a little more separation between the edge and the label for avoid this. Here is a sample of the figure code:

```
\begin{figure}[H] \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto, node    distance=3cm,thick, main node/.style={circle, draw, font=\sffamily\Large}]
    \node[main node] (1) {\textbf{A}};
    \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {B};
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}, label distance=9pt]
    (1) edge [right] node[left, below] {$\begin{aligned}
        \alpha_{A1} &+ \sum_{i',m',o'}\gamma_{i'\rightarrow A\ \ o'\rightarrow1} &=& \gamma_{A\rightarrow B\ \ 1\rightarrow 2} &+& \beta_{A1}\\
        1&+0 &=& 1 &+&0
        \end{aligned}$} (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Situação \ref{it:eq:setup_flow2} quando o produto A está entre dois itens.}
    \label{fig:eq:setup_flow2}
\end{figure}
```

I would appreciate a lot your help.[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may use `below=20pt` (or whatever measure you want):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H] \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto, node    distance=3cm,thick, main node/.style={circle, draw, font=\sffamily\Large}]
    \node[main node] (1) {\textbf{A}};
    \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {B};
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}, label distance=9pt]
   (1) edge [right] node[below=20pt] {\(
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt} % this is optional, you may remove or increase it
    \begin{array}{*{7}c}
        \alpha_{A1} & + & \displaystyle\sum_{i',m',o'}\gamma_{i'\rightarrow A\ \ o'\rightarrow1} & = & \gamma_{A\rightarrow B\ \ 1\rightarrow 2} & + & \beta_{A1}\\
        1 & + & 0 & = & 1 & + & 0
    \end{array}
    \)}  (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Situação \ref{it:eq:setup_flow2} quando o produto A está entre dois itens.}
    \label{fig:eq:setup_flow2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

EDITs:

As Torbjørn T. suggested, I removed the useless `left` in the node position.

Moreover, I've used an `array` instead of `aligned`, in this way the equation alignment looks better for me:

[image]

P.S. = since your MWE is not complete I've invented the preamble. The ?? appears since there is not the corresponding label.

Comment: I think that in `node[left, below=20pt]` the `left` does nothing at all, so can be removed.

Comment: Remark: in the general case (maybe `auto, sloped`; or if the user want it to be tighter instead of looser) adjust `inner sep`. -- briefly mentioned in section "17.12.2 — Nodes on Edges: Quotes Syntax", TikZ manual.